# PHP Как правильно вывести большой PDF файл в браузер?

Tags: php, файлы

```
$file_path = 'http://www.ifcmarkets.ru/pdf/forexbook/en/Forex_Trading_Strategies.pdf';

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function fileRandLine($file)
{
    $f = fopen($file, "r");
    while (!feof($f)) {
    $line = fgets($f);
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($f);
}

echo fileRandLine($file_path);
```

На экран выходят какие то кракозябры.

Ребята что я делаю не так И оптимален ли мой код или есть более лучший способ ?

Спасибо.

Comment: Используйте readfile() + header().

Comment: @Visman  Добавьте пожалуйста рабочий вариант вашего предложения

Comment: Есть мнение, что пдф закодирован как то иначе, и так его не вывести. Хотя могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Visman объединил с Вашим ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо подсказать браузеру, что Вы отдаете не текст (text/html), а pdf.
Плюс использование readfile будет значительно легче по ресурсам.

полный ответ:

```
$file_path = 'http://www.ifcmarkets.ru/pdf/forexbook/en/Forex_Trading_Strategies.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
readfile($file_path);
```